# VB.net SQL Backup with user choosing path

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, backup

I am trying to figure out how to program a SQL Server backup through a button click on my application, allowing the user to choose the path in which it's saved.

So far I have the following but I am stuck on how to proceed.

```
Private Sub Backup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Backup.Click

    Dim sqlconnectionstring As String = "Data Source=ressqlxd023.silver.com\int;Initial Catalog=hw3qwq_c51twed;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim conn As New sqlconnection(sqlconnectionstring)
    conn.open()
    Dim cmd As New sqlcommand
    cmd.connection = conn
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: You need to ask your user about the folder (FolderBrowserDialog) and then prepare the appropriate command text to execute (search for T-SQL BACKUP command)

Comment: Thanks Steve, so I store the FolderBrowserDialog as a string and pass it through to the backup path I am assuming.  I will search on T-SQL backup as well.

Comment: You haven't specified what kind of app is this. FolderBroserDialog is a class for WinForms (and probably could be used in WPF as well) You need to create an instance of this class and let the use choose the path. Read the _SelectedPath_ property and use it to prepare the BACKUP command

Comment: Thanks again Steve.  This is a desktop app where users will connect to the SQL Server.  I was hoping to have a spot to put backups, but currently there is no set space, so until that happens users are going to be directed to a shared network drive.